# What's the meaning of Self.XXX for a static variable

Tags: swift, swiftui

Just a example code for using Self to a static value.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var type = "girl"

    static let types = ["girl", "boy"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Picker("Type", selection: $type) {
                    ForEach(Self.types, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it mean the `types` is a static value, so it is needed to add the Self before to link to the ContentView?

Answer (score 1):

In short, 'Self' means a type of the instance. In your case Self.types is the same as ContentView.types. And yes, to access static variable you must use type or Self.

Comment: Or you can use `type(of: self).types`. But of course `Self.types` is better.